# Cluster specification in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I need some guidance on Azure Databricks as I am trying it for first time.First, I need to select the right cluster specification considering I have around 1.5 TB of log data to be scanned. these are logs data which are getting ingested in Storage account from Azure Diagnostics.Daily ingestion is around 100 GB/day and I will be required to do scanning for 30-60 days.

What cluster specification should I consider. It will be good to get some advice here with proper explaination. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things to consider when determining configuration options are:

•   What type of user will be using the cluster? A data scientist may be running different job types with different requirements than a data engineer or data analyst.

•   What types of workloads will users run on the cluster? For example, batch extract, transform, and load (ETL) jobs will likely have different requirements than analytical workloads.

•   What level of service level agreement (SLA) do you need to meet?

•   What budget constraints do you have?

For more information follow this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/cluster-config-best-practices)

Comment: It will be mostly used for analysis and investigating Audit logs.. The query mostly will be run by our Security team to investigate the generated logs from Azure Diagnostics. it will be run quite frequent  for scanning 1 Tb of data. the size of data is as i have mentioned in the question. Budget is what I am analyzing right now and hence this question